# Silverlight 5 breaking Silverlight 4 application

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I recently installed silverlight 5 and started working on new project based on SL5 version but after installing SL5 all my previous applications built on SL4 are not working and when i run these applications, XAP is getting downloaded and I am getting complete white screen as soon as it completed downloading XAP file and getting "AG_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR".

FYI: Everything works fine when i browse these SL4 based applications (hosted on my system) from a different system having only SL4 plugin.

Is there any known compatibility issue exists with SL4 & SL5 plugins running parallel? Kindly let me  know any workarounds for this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Binding to Resource Files 
You should update the constructor back to the public.

Also it might be possible that you web services references were broken